# Reading from input files in haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, io

I am solving [Project Euler Problem 11](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11). I have copy-pasted the table in the problem into a file called "input.txt". Each line of the input file contains a row of a 20x20 matrix, and the columns are separated by whitespace.

What I want is a function that reads this file, and returns it as an IO Array. I'm having huge trouble doing this.

So far I've done this:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main = readFile "input.txt"
```

This of course only gives me the IO String representation of the input file, but everything I try seems to fail. How should I proceed? I know I should do something like

```
array ((1,1),(20,20)) [ the numbers tupled with their indices ]
```

but converting the numbers is outright impossible for me, most likely because I do not entirely understand monads yet.

I am confident that this is in fact quite easy, once you understand it.

Does anyone have a suggestion about what to do?

Comment: What is the format of `input.txt`?

Comment: What do you mean? It's a txt-file and I just copy-pasted the matrix into it.

Comment: @Undreren: It's important to tell people what the format of your "input.txt" is. I mean, it could be the collected works of Shakespeare, it could have a floating point number of every odd numbered line and the name of a cat on every even numbered line, or it could, as in your case, contain 20 lines with 20 space-separated integers each. I only found that out from reading the problem you're trying to solve -- it's something that should be in the question.

Comment: OK, I just thought that linking to the matrix was neater since it used too much space.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: Might want to consider using the excellent `vector` package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse your file with something like this:

```
s = "2 4\n6 8"

s' :: [Int]
s' = (map read . words) s

let arr = listArray ((1,1),(2,2)) s'
-- arr == array ((1,1),(2,2)) [((1,1),2),((1,2),4),((2,1),6),((2,2),8)]
```

By combining `words` with `map read` (where `read :: (Read a) => String -> a`) you get a list `[Int]`.

So, in order to organize things a little bit, your code in the IO monad may look like this (assuming that every row has the same fixed number of columns and that you take the input file name, the number of rows and of columns as commandline arguments):

```
module Main

where

import Data.Array
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment

readWords :: (Read a) => String -> [a]
readWords = map read . words

parseFile :: String -> Int -> Int -> IO (Array (Int, Int) Int)
parseFile fname rows cols = do
    matr <- liftM readWords $ readFile fname
    return $ listArray ((1, 1), (rows, cols)) matr
    -- (matr :: [Int] is inferred from the parseFile's type)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        [fname, rows, cols] -> do
            arr <- parseFile fname (read rows) (read cols)
            print arr
```

Note how the conversion function `readWords` is able to convert to any `[a]` provided that `Read a`, so that we don't restrict ourselves to integers only.
The `liftM` function takes a pure function (our `readWords`) and "lifts" it to work in the current monad, i.e. `IO`.

Comment: With the given format, a simple `map read . words` is enough, no reason to split it into lines and `concat` at the end in this case. Of course splitting the input into lines is the generally more useful way.

Comment: @DanielFischer: lol you're right, I'm going to correct it in the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole program should be like this:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Array

main = do
    content <- readFile "input.txt"
    let matrix = map (map read . words) $ lines content     -- [[Int]]
    let arr = listArray ((1, 1), (20, 20)) (concat matrix)
    putStr $ solve arr
```

Where `solve` is the function of type `Array (Int, Int) Int -> String`.

Comment: This won't even compile? I removed the `solve` part of `putStr` to test if it works, and it doesn't.

Comment: I guess the problem is with the type inference for `read`. Try forcing the `let matrix` to be of type `[[Int]]`.